# Plot command yields wrong value?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to do a plot of integrals of Mathieu functions, which are built in functions in *Mathematica*. My problem is that it seems that `Plot` gives the wrong result with a factor of 2 in my case.

My code is

```
Clear["Global`*"];
q[λ_, L_] := (λ*L^2)/(4*π^2)
al[l_, λ_, L_] := MathieuCharacteristicA[l, q[λ, L]]
MCos[l_, λ_, L_, z_] := 
MathieuC[al[l, λ, L], q[λ, L], z]
Dp[k_, l_, λ_, L_] := (2/(π*L))*
NIntegrate[(Exp[-I*k*z])*MCos[0, λ, L, z]*
MCos[l, λ, L, z], {z, 0, π}]

Plot[{
Sqrt[q[λ, 1]] Abs[Dp[1, 1, λ, 1]]^2,
Sqrt[q[1000, 1]] Abs[Dp[1, 1, 1000, 1]]^2},
{λ, 10, 1000}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.6}]
```

[image]

Analytically, I know that the exact limit is 1/4, and not 1/2 which the `Plot` command gives. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a long comment pointing out what fails here (but with no solution proposed, though).

The issue is in `NIntegrate` (the same applies to `Integrate`, but the computations take more time). The functions `q`, `al` and `MCos` seem to be ok.

`Dp` itself is a very computationaly expensive function, which gives not very numericaly trustworthy values:

```
Abs[Dp[1, 100,  1, 1]]^2
Abs[Dp[1, 100., 1, 1]]^2
```

> 7.90282*10^-9
>
> 7.90282*10^-9

```
Abs[Dp[1, 300,  1, 1]]^2
Abs[Dp[1, 300., 1, 1]]^2
```

> 9.75498*10^-11
>
> 9.75498*10^-11

```
Abs[Dp[1, 1000,  1, 1]]^2
Abs[Dp[1, 1000., 1, 1]]^2
```

> 7.90139*10^-13
>
> no result in a reasonable time

They are not trustworthy because they're are very small and likely to lead to numerical artifacts, and

```
f[a_] := Sqrt[q[a, 1]] Abs[Dp[1, 1, a, 1]]^2
```

works very fast - much faster than `Dp` alone.

Now, the issue is in `NIntegrate` because

```
{ f[100],  f[100.]}
{ f[300],  f[300.]}
{f[1000], f[1000.]}
```

> {0.255864, 0.511728}
>
> {0.249298, 0.498596}
>
> {0.249872, 0.499745}

Also

```
{f[201/2], f[100.5]}
```

> {0.255729, 0.511459}

**Exact values give proper results, numerical give erroneous ones.**

```
ListPlot[Table[f[i], {i, 10, 300, 10}], PlotRange -> {0, 0.6}]
```

[image]

but

```
ListPlot[Table[f[i], {i, 10., 300, 10}], PlotRange -> {0, 0.6}]
```

[image]

and `Plot` uses numerical values:

```
Plot[f[a], {a, 10, 300}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.6}]
```

[image]

A `ListPlot` for other exact values is also correct:

```
ListPlot[Table[f[i], {i, 10, 300, 1/3}], PlotRange -> {0, 0.6}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did not understand that this was the difference in the Plot command, but your examples makes it very clear. It is a bit strange that even for small values of the input parameter, where the integrand is  actually well-behaved, there is still a large difference between 10 and 10.0. However, I guess that is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is not a problem of `Plot` but of `NIntegrate` in your definition of `Dp`. If you use just `Integrate` and evaluate the expressions at the end numerically, it works fine (but takes very long).

```
Clear["Global`*"];
q[λ_, L_] := (λ*L^2)/(4*π^2)
al[l_, λ_, L_] := MathieuCharacteristicA[l, q[λ, L]]
MCos[l_, λ_, L_, z_] := MathieuC[al[l, λ, L], q[λ, L], z]
Dp[k_, l_, λ_, L_] := 
  (2/(π*L))*Integrate[(Exp[-I*k*z])*MCos[0, λ, L, z]*MCos[l, λ, L, z], {z, 0, π}]
f[l_] := N[Sqrt[q[l, 1]] Abs[Dp[1, 1, l, 1]]^2]
data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 10^3, 10^2}];
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! However, I still think the problem is with Plot. If I replace Integrate with NIntegrate in your code, I get the same plot as you, but much quicker. Thus, calling the function pointwise works, and gives the correct result.